# CS50 inheritance lab5

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I am currently taking the cs50 course and i attempted the inheritance lab5 problem but in the course of writing my code i encountered a segmentation fault error  and  i really cannot seem to wrap my head around the cause of this error. please i would like to get assistance and correction on this issue to know what exactly the problem is and how i can avoid it.

*the code compiles but every other task can not be completed because of a segmentation fault*

```
// Simulate genetic inheritance of blood type

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Each person has two parents and two alleles
typedef struct person
{
    struct person *parents[2];
    char alleles[2];
}
person;

const int GENERATIONS = 3;
const int INDENT_LENGTH = 4;

person *create_family(int generations);
void print_family(person *p, int generation);
void free_family(person *p);
char random_allele();

int main(void)
{
    // Seed random number generator
    srand(time(0));

    // Create a new family with three generations
    person *p = create_family(GENERATIONS);

    // Print family tree of blood types
    print_family(p, 0);

    // Free memory
    free_family(p);
}

// Create a new individual with `generations`
person *create_family(int generations)
{
    // TODO: Allocate memory for new person
    person *newperson = malloc(sizeof(person));

    // If there are still generations left to create
    if (generations > 1)
    {
        // Create two new parents for current person by recursively calling create_family
        person *parent0 = create_family(generations - 1);
        person *parent1 = create_family(generations - 1);

        // TODO: Set parent pointers for current person

        newperson->parents[0] = parent0;
        newperson->parents[1] = parent1;


        // TODO: Randomly assign current person's alleles based on the alleles of their parents

        newperson->alleles[0] = parent0->alleles[rand() %2];
        newperson->alleles[1] = parent1->alleles[rand() %2];


    }

    // If there are no generations left to create
    else
    {
        // TODO: Set parent pointers to NULL
        newperson->parents[0] = NULL;
        newperson->parents[1] = NULL;

        // TODO: Randomly assign alleles
        newperson->alleles[0] = random_allele();
        newperson->alleles[1] = random_allele();

    }

    // TODO: Return newly created person
    return newperson;
    //return NULL;
}

// Free `p` and all ancestors of `p`.
void free_family(person *p)
{
    // TODO: Handle base case
    if ( p == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // TODO: Free parents recursively
    free_family(p->parents[0]);
    free_family(p->parents[1]);

    // TODO: Free child
    free_family(p);
    return;

}

// Print each family member and their alleles.
void print_family(person *p, int generation)
{
    // Handle base case
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Print indentation
    for (int i = 0; i < generation * INDENT_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    // Print person
    if (generation == 0)
    {
        printf("Child (Generation %i): blood type %c%c\n", generation, p->alleles[0], p->alleles[1]);
    }
    else if (generation == 1)
    {
        printf("Parent (Generation %i): blood type %c%c\n", generation, p->alleles[0], p->alleles[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < generation - 2; i++)
        {
            printf("Great-");
        }
        printf("Grandparent (Generation %i): blood type %c%c\n", generation, p->alleles[0], p->alleles[1]);
    }

    // Print parents of current generation
    print_family(p->parents[0], generation + 1);
    print_family(p->parents[1], generation + 1);
}

// Randomly chooses a blood type allele.
char random_allele()
{
    int r = rand() % 3;
    if (r == 0)
    {
        return 'A';
    }
    else if (r == 1)
    {
        return 'B';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'O';
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Launch your favourite debugger and find the exact line crashing. Then check the values of all variables involved at the crash and see which one that is fishy. Seg faults can also be caused by excessive recursion = stack overflow.

Comment: `free_family` is wrong/incomplete - its infinitely recursive which is likely the cause of the seg fault, and you are not actually doing anything to free the memory, nor null out the pointers so that you don't inadvertently use them again.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite recursion in `free_family` is likely the cause of the seg fault.

You aren't actually freeing the memory assocated with the person.

As a point of note, its good practice to set the pointer to null so that you know its now an invalid pointer.  You might need to modify the signature to a `person **` to allow you to modify it within the function.

```
// Free `p` and all ancestors of `p`.
void free_family(person *p)
{
    // TODO: Handle base case
    if ( p == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    free_family(p->parents[0]);
    free_family(p->parents[1]);

    free_family(p);
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is infinitely recursive
    return;

}
```

A solution:

```
void free_family(person **p)
{
    // TODO: Handle base case
    if ( *p == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // TODO: Free parents recursively
    free_family(&(*p)->parents[0]);
    free_family(&(*p)->parents[1]);

    // TODO: Free child
    free(*p);
    *p = NULL;
    return;

}
```

Use like:

```
int main(void)
{
    // Seed random number generator
    srand(time(0));

    // Create a new family with three generations
    person *p = create_family(GENERATIONS);

    // Print family tree of blood types
    print_family(p, 0);

    // Free memory
    free_family(&p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // TODO: Free child
    free_family(p);
    return;
```

In this part you are recursively freeing the child while all you need to do is free the child only once. What you need to do is:

```
// TODO: Free child
    free(p);
    return;
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

you were calling free_family recursively even for the child. Instead of freeing the child using the same function, use free(p);- so that the function will have a base case.